# Enters elif block regardless of input

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to execute the following:

```
print("Are you old enough to vote? Please enter your age below:")
input()

age = 18

if age < 18:
    print('You must be 18 to vote.')

elif age >= 18:
    print ('You are of voting age.')
```

When I run it, the program prints "You are of voting age" no matter how low the number input is.

Comment: You completely ignore the `input()` result and set `age = 18` no matter what. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning age to a fixed variable and never changing it from the user input.

```
age = 18
```

Then,

```
if age >= 18:
```

Will always execute that code block.

You need to assign age from your `input()`.

You could do something like:

```
age_string = input()
if age_value.isdigit():   # is a number
    age = int(age_string)
```

Then execute the if/then statement.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I couldn't figure out how to change the variable based on the user input.